# Where does mass come from?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, quarks, higgs, quark-gluon-plasma

I've read material claiming it comes from the Higgs boson fails while others claim it is from the tensions of quarks in the gluon field... I am only a 15 year old kid in high school so please "dumb it down"

Comment: Have you seen the [video by Veritasium](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ztc6QPNUqls&feature=c4-overview&list=UUHnyfMqiRRG1u-2MsSQLbXA)?

Comment: Yes that is what confused me since all other sources say it is for Higgs...

Comment: Well in that video(and also another video), creating that empty space between those quarks takes a lot of energy. That energy contributes to the majority of the mass of the object, the Higgs field contributes for the rest. So what is your question exactly?

Comment: So rather it is that both of them are true and create mass?

Comment: That's what he says. Maybe someone else here can confirm this...

Comment: Do you have any idea in what percentage I the mass each creates

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64232/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Mass is interaction. Most mass we observe is due to the interaction amongst quarks. A tiny remainder is due to other interactions including the interaction with the Higgs field.

Comment: Protip: even those spell-checkers that do pretty well with basic technical vocabulary are likely to be lacking when it comes to more specialized terms, so it isn't safe to trust then.